# Reading from stderr instead of stdin

Tags: c, linux, stdin, stderr, unistd.h

I ran into code like this in the wild, and I'm wondering why this works.
The code reads from stderr (fd==2) instead of stdin (fd==0). The wierd thing is this actually works somewhat. You can read typing at the console, but not piped input. Any idea what is going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
   char buf[15];
   int nchars=read(2,buf,15);
   printf("%d '%s'\n",nchars,buf);
}
```

Comment: Your title says "Reading from stderr instead of stderr" which makes no sense\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! This works because when you are at the console in the terminal, STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR all ultimately point to the same resource: `/dev/tty` (or whatever your platform calls it). The three file descriptors are the same file opened 3 times (possibly with different options).

When you pipe content, that is no longer the case and this broken code no longer works since stdin is now one thing while stdout/stderr is another.

In your code sample it makes no sense to do so and would be best described as a bug. But perhaps the author of that "code in the wild" was trying to do something different and had his or her reasons for doing so. Do you have a reference for that code sample you found?

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/8969a855132a27769dd6399566dc86ac32b26e76/riscv/interactive.cc#L82   I think its a bug

Comment: Actually there was just an answer to an issue I raised on that repo: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/issues/124#issuecomment-329922070. Looks like it was intentional.